# SDL/c++ drawing by holding mouse button

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm new in working with SDL and now I've faced a problem.
Well, I'm about to make a program like Paint.
In order to do that I need a command for mouse that when I'm holding the left button and moving the mouse, a line would be drawing in  where the mouse is going.
I have found an event for it, SDL_MouseButtonDown. but it only works for one second like I only click on the screen for one time!

I will appreciate any comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event fires when the button goes down. It doesn't repeatedly fire for as long as the button *is* down, and this wouldn't be of much use to you anyway.

Write your code so that you set some variable when the button goes down, and unset it when `SDL_MouseButtonUp` is invoked. Whenever the mouse moves, *and* your variable is set, draw more of the line.